# Textarea gettong outside the container

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please check the below fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/a13nd32u/3/

```
 <textarea rows="5" cols="50" style="width:95%;height:90%;overflow:hidden">
 What's on your mind?
 </textarea>
```

Here when I am trying to expand the textarea vertically then it box is getting outside the box. I want to implement it such that whenever the user expand the textarea vertically , the div background should also be expand with it. Can anyone please provide a solution

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
 <div class="divv">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="65"></textarea>
      <h4>
        space
      </h4>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divv{
    background-color:green;
 }
textarea {
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4jsz2nyb/15/)
See if it helps

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
#container {
background-color: #e6e6e6;
border-style: double;
float: left;
height: auto;
min-height: 160px;
padding-top: 5px;
width: 470px;
}
```

Comment: Its causing the texarea to occupy the full page ..not the desired result mate :(

Comment: You could mark this response as the answer to your problem so other people see what solved it. :) Same goes for your other questions ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/aa0mkvfz/:

```
#container {
    border-style: double;
    width: 470px;
    height: 160px;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    padding-top: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}
hr {
    border-color: #FAFAFA;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}
#upper_space {
    color: #3b5998;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#textbox {
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}
#post_part {
    display: inline;
    padding: 6px 9px;
    float: right;
    font-size: 15px
}
select {
    width: 80px;
    height: 21px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: inline
}
#button1 {
    display: inline;
    padding-left: 10px
}
#post_button {
    height: 24px;
    width: 70px;
    font-size: 14px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

All I did was add an `overflow:auto;` on the required divs, this creates a new block formatting context, please check this document to learn more about it:
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-block-formatting-contexts-in-css/

Comment: Nope mate. I need a facebook type post box. this is not desired

Comment: I finally understood what you want, it can be done with `overflow:auto` this is the css you need `#container{
 border-style: double;width:470px;min-height:160px;background-color:#E6E6E6;padding-top:5px;overflow:auto;}`